# jQuery selector context doesn't match outermost element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following snippet, why is the length is 0 when it should be 1?

```js
var jQueryObj = $("<p>testing</p>");
// Display the length
$('body').html($("p", jQueryObj).length);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide the context, you are telling jQuery to find the `p` element inside that context, so your selector will look for any `p` tag that is a child of the context.

If you add a container to the context, it will be able to find that element.

```js
var jQueryObj = $("<div><p>testing</p></div>");
// Display the length
$('body').html($("p", jQueryObj).length);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a context to jQuery, it's equivalent to using the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, which looks at descendent elements. From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

Your `p` element is not a descendant, so you would need to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
jQueryObj.filter("p");
```

The `filter` method reduces the matched set of elements to those that match the selector (or pass a test defined by a function). In your case, the matched set of elements contains one element (the `p`), which will match the selector.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no `<p>` element within you `jQueryObj`.

Using `jQueryObj` as a context will limite the search for the provided selector to the context. It is the same as writing:

```
jQueryObj.find('p');
```

Internally, jquery actually uses .find() when you use the syntax `$(selector, context)`, as stated in the doc:

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

Further reading:

- [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
- [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

**You are searching for `<p>` inside your original `<p>`** (`jQueryObj` already represents a `<p>` tag).

Because there is no `<p>` element within your original `<p>` element, your search does not return any results.